# Jquery select single item for fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, jquery-effects

Learning jquery.

Currently I have this bit of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.portfolio img').mouseover(function() {
        console.log('hover succes');
        $('.thumbnail-overlay').fadeIn();
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.thumbnail-overlay').fadeOut();
    })

});
```

Obviously not ideal since I have a .portfolio section with images but the effect is applied to all images at once. How do I only get the currently hovered item selected for the effect?

Comment: what's the relation between `.thumbnail-overlay` and `.portfolio img`?

Comment: Need to see your html for an exact answer. But basically, use `$(this)` in your handler to get a reference to the event target, then traverse the DOM using the [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) functions to the element you want to act on. Alternatively, if traversing isn't an option, you can give the two sets of elements related classes.

Comment: .thumbnail-overlay is placed above the img as a black transparent block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to do this make sure the single *img* element and *.thumbnail-overlay* both have a common parent element.

Like this (where the parent is *.portfolio*):

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="thumbnail-overlay"></div>
    <img>
</div>
```

Now you can access the *.thumbnail-overlay* using `$(this).closest('.portfolio').find('.thumbnail-overlay')`

OR make sure the *img* element is a child of *.thumbnail-overlay*.

Like this:

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="thumbnail-overlay">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div class="thumbnail-overlay">
    <div class="portfolio">
        <img>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then get the *.thumbnail-overlay* using `$(this).closest('.thumbnail-overlay')`.